# How to integrate Metronic theme code in angular-seed-advanced

Tags: angular, metronic, angular-seed-advanced

anyone please let me know that how we can integrate metronic theme code in angular-seed-advanced.

Please share the link or all the possible steps so that it can be configured perfectly in angular seed projects.

Comment: I think it's already seeded with the necessary, what you expect?